# Bitbucket: Help needed moving updates from fork to upstream

Tags: git, bitbucket

I need some guidance if someone is willing to help. I have a project called MainProject and a fork of it called ForkedProject. These projects contain both code AND data, but I have my .gitignore ignoring data directories.

I've come to the part where I need to move my updates upstream from ForkedProject to MainProject.

I'm going to make a copy of my production project as is from one server to another, after which, I would like to move all of my updates from ForkedProject to MainProject.

Nearly all (but not all) changes have been done on the master branch.

I'm not 100% confident in my git skills so I apologise in advance, but I have done some Googling and not always sure about what I'm reading.

Is it possible to incorporate everything that's changed in ForkedProject into an entirely new branch to then push up to MainProject?

Can someone help me with the steps I would need to do to push my changes upstream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Pull request](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request) should work for your case

since the ForkedRepo is well, forked from your mainRepo, a PR into the main repo:master from the forkedRepo:master should get all the committed changes from forked Repo into the main repo.

barring merge conflicts, this should do the trick.

in case of merge conflicts, a good idea is to tackle the conflicts from the forkedRepo itself, and then issueing a PR

you can do that by going into your forked repo code and [pulling changes](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing)

```
git remote add mainRepo <mainRepoUrl>
git pull mainRepo master --rebase  # rebase adds your last commit on ForkRepo to the top of the commits
```

**Note** You can do the same thing from the mainRepo by adding forkedRepo as a remote and merging forkedRepo:master into master, and pushing the changes into BitBucket. If you need the code reviewed by someone, then Pull Request is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. I did forget to mention that I have been continuously merging downstream from MainRepo to ForkedRepo, since development on both has been going on, and resolving conflicts where they arise. I _don't imagine_ too much in the way of conflict, and I can solve them if they appear when going upstream. Thank you for your help.